# Can I remove *.o file (Code::Blocks)

Tags: c++, file, codeblocks

Can I remove *.o file after I compiled a program? If I wanted to modify a program and then compile it again would the absence of this file be a source of problems?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to remove the object files?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Code::Blocks`, but in general any `*.o` files are temporary and can be deleted after the program is compiled.

Comment: Yes, you can remove it. BUT, if you program consists of multiple files and you change one of them, lack of `.o`s would make CB recompile the entire program (once) instead of just the changed file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't be a problem since *.o files are object files which is basically your program compiled.
In fact if you try to recompile the program, you will notice that the *.o files will be regenerated

Answer (score 1):

Object files are the result of *compilation*. Afterwards, these files are *linked* to an executable.

So yes, you can remove those safely (if all you want is the executable file).